# where should i put the WHERE Clause

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Where should I put the `WHERE` clause here.

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM students  LIMIT $startResults, $resultsPerPage");
```

Comment: Have you thought about reading the MySQL manual on `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Or, you know, using Google?

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this :

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM students WHERE (condition) LIMIT $startResults, $resultsPerPage");
```

Answer (score 1):

... your question is kind of vague but....

normally people make a query a single string, and if i'm guessing what your asking right:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM students WHERE `mysql_field`='$somevalue' LIMIT $number_of_results_you_want_returned";
```

bare in mind the query above does not prevent against sql injextion attacks...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE character='willing to learn' AND Age < 35 LIMIT $startResults, $resultsPerPage
```

`WHERE` and (if necessary) `AND` inserted

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM students WHERE <where_condition> LIMIT $startResults, $resultsPerPage");
```